# how to calculate the ratio from series in pandas after groupby?

Tags: pandas

I have a series like this:
the first column is user_id and the second column is a flag to represent how many times in reordered=0/1. Some users have no reordered, for example , the user 21.
I want to get a new columns ratio, which is from times(0)/times(1&0).
for example, for user 1, the ratio is 1 / (1+10). How can I do this.

```
user_id  reordered
1        0.0           1
         1.0          10
15       0.0           1
         1.0           4
19       0.0           1
         1.0           2
21       0.0           1
31       0.0           1
         1.0           1
43       0.0           1
         1.0           1
52       0.0           1
         1.0          13
67       0.0           1
         1.0          19
81       0.0           1
         1.0           1
82       0.0           1
         1.0           8
98       0.0           1
         1.0           6
109      0.0           1
120      0.0           1
         1.0           1
185      0.0           1
```

[image]

Comment: my series's name is dff and it it produced in this way dff = df.groupby(['user_id','reordered'])['order_id'].count()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(dff.xs(0, level='reordered') / dff.groupby(level='user_id').sum()).rename('ratio')

user_id
1      0.090909
15     0.200000
19     0.333333
21     1.000000
31     0.500000
43     0.500000
52     0.071429
67     0.050000
81     0.500000
82     0.111111
98     0.142857
109    1.000000
120    0.500000
185    1.000000
Name: ratio, dtype: float64
```

Comment: my series's name is dff and it it produced in this way dff = df.groupby(['user_id','reordered'])['order_id'].count()

Comment: @yanachen what are you trying to tell me.  Can you adjust what you need to in oder to suit your purpose?

Comment: The output is exactly what I want. But when i replace the s with dff based on your code, it comes some error. and I paste the error message in the question. Plz see it. Thanks.

Comment: @yanachen difference in pandas version.  I've updated post

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
diff
user_id  reordered
1        0             1
         1            10
15       0             1
         1             4
19       0             1
         1             2
21       0             1
31       0             1
         1             1
43       0             1
         1             1
52       0             1
         1            13
67       0             1
         1            19
81       0             1
         1             1
82       0             1
         1             8
98       0             1
         1             6
109      0             1
120      0             1
         1             1
185      0             1
```

**Solution**

```
#group by userid, sum count on 0s and then divide by sum of all.
diff.name = 'count'    
diff.reset_index().groupby('user_id').apply(lambda x: x[x.reordered==0]['count'].sum()/float(x['count'].sum()))

user_id
1      0.090909
15     0.200000
19     0.333333
21     1.000000
31     0.500000
43     0.500000
52     0.071429
67     0.050000
81     0.500000
82     0.111111
98     0.142857
109    1.000000
120    0.500000
185    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: my series's name is dff and it it produced in this way dff = df.groupby(['user_id','reordered'])['order_id'].count()